# C# Consume WebService authenticated via FormsAuthentication Method

Tags: c#, web-services, forms-authentication, webclient

so my question is very simple, how could I consume a WebService which is protected by a FormsAuthentication method (aka Cookie's style) ?

Because I've my WinForms application that can't consume authenticated WebServices.

I already saw the WebClient method, do you thing is usefull to what I want to do ?

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

I don't really found an answer about that !

The only thing I've done, is to protect all the Web pages I need to protect using Forms Authentication, and then consume my famous WebService in order to use it with my application.

Thank you anyway to you all !